# What is the roster form of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set $$A = \{x:x\in \mathbb{Z}^+, x<10 \text{ and } 2^{x}-1\text{ is odd}\}$$

Shouldn't the Roster form be :

$$A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$

?

or would it be $$A = \{(2^{1}-1), (2^{2}-1), (2^{3}-1) ... (2^{9}-1) \}$$

And can we write this in set builder form : $\{x^2 : x\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ? can we write an expression before such that sign in set builder form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first guess is right and if you read the math regarding $x$ carefully you'll see why.

Counter question: Is $2^9-1 < 10$?

You could just write $A = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : x < 10\}$.

Comment: No! actually i think it is completely wrong. i think first one should be correct. else they would have given $\{2^{x}-1 : x\in \mathbb{Z}^+, x< 10\}$

Comment: @TimKrul There is no need to think or guess in these type of questions, just work precisely and you'll obtain the correct answer.